# FitPolicy does not work based on canvas width on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-native-pdf

This error only happens on iOS platform.

```
"react-native": "0.72.4",
"react-native-blob-util": "^0.19.6",
"react-native-pdf": "^6.7.4",
[![enter code here][1]][1]
```

In iOS, the first image of my pdf file is quite small compared to the other images. Think of it as a picture cropped in half.
I think it takes the size of the whole pdf according to the size of the first canvas. That's why I can't see the whole big image on the screen.

I have tried:

FitPolicy 0/1/2 all with the same result
I set the scale value smaller than normal

```
container: { // style for the view that wraps the pdf
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  pdf: { // for pdf 
    flex: 1,
    width: Dimensions.get('screen').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('screen').height,
   // screen or window values make no difference.
  },
```

this is what I get in my native pdf viewer, but in the pdf package the cat image takes up the whole screen horizontally and the next image does not fit on the screen.
note: zooming out the image is not a solution for me.

Your help and feedback is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

- When you set the fitPolicy to 2, it scales the PDF to fit the screen height. This can sometimes result in images being cropped or not fitting the screen properly.
- PDF viewer component

  ```
  import React, { useState } from 'react';
  import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
  import PDFView from 'react-native-pdf';

  const PDFViewer = ({ source }) => {
   const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('screen').width;
   const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('screen').height;
   const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);

   const handlePageChanged = (page) => {
    setCurrentPage(page);
   };

   const fitPolicy = currentPage === 1 ? 2 : 1; // Adjust the fitPolicy based on the current page

   return (
    <PDFView
      source={source}
      style={{ width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight }}
      fitPolicy={fitPolicy}
      onPageChanged={handlePageChanged}
    />
   );
  };
  ```
- variable currentPage to keep track of the current page. The fitPolicy is set to 2 if the currentPage is 1, otherwise it's set to 1. This ensures that the first page is scaled to fit the screen height, while the rest of the pages are scaled to fit the screen width

Comment: yes i use it. but still some images have inside scrolling and it prevents me from moving to the next page.

Comment: @muazzez check i update my code

Comment: thanks for helping @pratik-prakash-bindage but I created my own pdf viewer, I don't use anymore this package